# Display alert and then jump to another form in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am working on J2ME application. I want to show alert in Form and display another Form from another class. I have tried the following method to show alert.

```
public void showMsg() 
    {
        Alert success = new Alert("Data Not found.");
        //success.setImage(img2);
       success.addCommand(new Command("Ok", Command.OK, 0));
       success.addCommand(new Command("Cancel", Command.CANCEL, 0));
       success.setCommandListener(this);
       success.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);

        Display.getDisplay(parent).setCurrent(success, chapterForm);
    }
```

After showing the alert I am jumping to another form as:

```
Display.getDisplay(parent).setCurrent(welcomeForm);
```

When I run this it don't show the alert but jump to the welComeForm. So, how can I show alert and then jump to another form.

Answer (score 1):

The Alert won't advance automatically to `chapterForm` because you have replaced the default listener on the Alert with `this`. Use the commandAction() event in the CommandListener interface to get the OK or Cancel from the Alert. Then you can use `Display.setCurrent(Displayable d)` to show the Form you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

`Display.getDisplay(parent).setCurrent(welcomeForm)` is most likely the reason why it *don't show the alert but jump to the welComeForm*. To be precise it (device) may show alert for a moment, but as soon as you invoke that `setCurrent(welcomeForm)`, it gets momentarily overwritten by welcomeForm.

If you want `welcomeForm` to be dissplayed by command from alert, just

1. wipe out the code `setCurrent(welcomeForm)` from where it is now
2. insert that wiped-out code into `this.commandAction` method (`this` is command listener you use in your code exerpt)

Answer (score 0):

A nifty solution is to start a new thread after setting the current display to the Alert, and in this new thread you can do a Thread.sleep(2000); in order to wait, and after that you display the new form.